# URL rewriting For WordPress - Integrating Non Wordpress site with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

We are unable to change the url rewriting to integrate an exsiting directory site into my wordpress site.

WordPress is fixing everything to their url pattern.

How can I help my programmer? Can someone give an advise?

Comment: he was frustrated but he managed to fix it after some browsing of answers provided below. we found a fix. so thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

More details would be useful, but in all likelihood, add a do nothing and stop rule for your folder **before the WP rules**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

We integrate WordPress with Ruby-on-Rails on [ICanLocalize](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/).

This is done in the Apache config file. Use the Apache *Alias* command to indicate that a path comes from a different physical directory.

Then, the URLs that match that path will never go to WordPress. They will be served from the other physical directory, where you can place anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take a subdirectory out of the url-rewriting from wordpress, put an additional `.htaccess` file into that directory and switch the Rewrite-Engine off:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

That directive overrides any settings of the wordpress `.htaccess` for that directory and it's subdirectories.

You find the longer version of my answer in a related question on [wordpress answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8536/wordpress-htaccess-subdirectory-problem/8538#8538) with a slightly different `.htaccess` code.